# Google Maps Markers and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-scope, google-maps-markers

I'm using Ionic (AngularJS + Cordova).
With the following code I've created marker with click event, but when I click on a marker, $scope.example isn't update in the view (but in console it display the id, function works). Why?
I think that the markers aren't compiled with AngularJS(?).

```
$scope.setInfoWindow = function(id){$scope.example = id;console.log(id)}

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latit,data[i].longi),
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            $scope.setInfoWindow(data[i].id);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular scope don't run its digest cycle while it dealing with event/ manipulating scope through events, At that time you need to run digest cycle manually.

After scope variable updation is done you need to run digest cycle manually. SO that it would update the binding on the View.

```
$scope.setInfoWindow = function(id){
   $scope.example = id;
   console.log(id)
   $scope.$apply(); //running digest cycle to update binding
}
```